# SQL I want to get the following output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a sales table

```
Date_s sales_man product qty
1-Jan-18   xx    01       30
1-Jan-18   xx    01       20
1-Jan-18   xy    01       20 
1-Feb-18   xz    02       10
5-Feb-18   xz    02       30
1-Feb-18   xx    01       10
1-Feb-18   xx    01       40
1-Mar-18   xy    03       20
```

I want to get the following output data format as

```
Product  sales_man  Jan  Feb   Mar
01       xx         50    10    0 
01       xy         20    0     0 
02       xx         0     0     0
02       xy         0     0     0
02       xz         0     0     0
03       xy         0     0     20
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: At least show what have you tried so far.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: This is my first question getting used to the format sorry for the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i got Your problem right, you can try:

```
SELECT * into #TempTable FROM 
(select product, salesman, qty, FORMAT(Dates, 'MMM') as Months from sales
) AS s 
PIVOT 
(
   SUM(qty)
   FOR Months in (Jan, Feb)
) AS Pvt



select product, salesman, isnull(Jan, 0) as Jan, isnull(Feb, 0) as Feb from 
#TempTable order by product

drop table #TempTable
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation.  Something like this:

```
select product, salesperson,
       sum(case when extract(month from dates) = 1 then qty else 0 end) as jan,
       sum(case when extract(month from dates) = 2 then qty else 0 end) as feb
from t
group by product, salesperson;
```

This uses ANSI SQL date functions, because your database tag is not clear.  Date operations can differ by database.

Also, when looking at data by month, typically, you want to take the year into account as well (by filtering or aggregating on the year).

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your date format from '1-Jan-18' to '1-01-18', then you can do below way

check sql fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d3824/2

If you consider below date format
'1-01-18',
'1-01-18',
'1-02-18';

then you can do this query

```
select product, salesman,
       sum(case when extract(month from dates) = 1 then qty else 0 end) as jan,
       sum(case when extract(month from dates) = 2 then qty else 0 end) as feb
from sales
group by product, salesman;
```

Result

```
product salesman    jan feb
1       xx          30  0
1       xz          0   20
2       xy          10  0
```

For all month

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d3824/9

for all do query like this,

```
select product, salesman,
       sum(case when extract(month from dates) = 1 then qty else 0 end) as jan,
       sum(case when extract(month from dates) = 2 then qty else 0 end) as feb,
       sum(case when extract(month from dates) = 3 then qty else 0 end) as mar,
       sum(case when extract(month from dates) = 4 then qty else 0 end) as apr,
       sum(case when extract(month from dates) = 5 then qty else 0 end) as may,
       sum(case when extract(month from dates) = 6 then qty else 0 end) as jun,
       sum(case when extract(month from dates) = 7 then qty else 0 end) as jul,
       sum(case when extract(month from dates) = 8 then qty else 0 end) as aug,
       sum(case when extract(month from dates) = 9 then qty else 0 end) as sep,
       sum(case when extract(month from dates) = 10 then qty else 0 end) as oct,
       sum(case when extract(month from dates) = 11 then qty else 0 end) as nov,
       sum(case when extract(month from dates) = 12 then qty else 0 end) as dece
from sales
group by product, salesman;
```

Result would be

```
product salesman    jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dece
1       xx          30  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1       xz          0   20  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2       xy          10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Please include the code in your answer. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i provided fiddle still i need to repeat query paste over here?

Comment: Yes - link only answers can be "invalid" very quickly and SQLFiddle is quite unreliable (at least to me: in 50% of the cases the fiddles don't even open). See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that you for your guidance. i updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer